# create a component that can have different display

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create my own graphical component in java.
I wish he could have different types of display:

1. A display representing a JPanel containing a JLabel in the center (pic 1)
2. A display representing a JPanel with a GridLayout (3,3). In this JPanel there will be 9 JPanel. Some of them may contain JLabel in the center (pic 2 and 3).

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

So I would like to know how to proceed: should I extends JComponent or JPanel ..?
I would also like to be able to go from one display to another, ie, following an actionPerformed, to be able to modify the view of the component by the simple call of a method.

I do not have a code yet, I'm just looking for a track to start this class. thank you in advance !

Comment: *"So I would like to know how to proceed: should I extends JComponent or JPanel ..?"* - That depends a lot on how you want to manage the code.  For example, you could simply create the panels via factory methods, which just instantiates a `JPanel` and sets up the components.  If there is additional functionality required for the labels/component (like monitoring the mouse), then it's possible that a custom component would be suitable, as it encapsulates the functionality and makes it more re-usable. You should also consider if there is any "common" functionality which they all share

Comment: *"I would also like to be able to go from one display to another, ie, following an actionPerformed"* - Then I suggest having a look at `CardLayout`, which will allow you to easily switch between different views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by creating your own JPanel and use [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

See a small example below:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    final static String PANEL1 = "p1";
    final static String PANEL2 = "p2";

    public MyPanel(){
        super();
        this.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        this.add(getFirstDisplay(),PANEL1); 
        this.add(getSecondDisplay(),PANEL2);
    }

    private JPanel getFirstDisplay() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.add(new JLabel("9"));

        return p;
    }

    private JPanel getSecondDisplay() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                p.add(new JLabel(""+counter));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return p;
    }

    public void loadPanel(String name) {

        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(this.getLayout());
        cl.show(this, name);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");

        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

        JButton b1 = new JButton("show 1");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myPanel.loadPanel(PANEL1);
            }
        });

        JButton b2 = new JButton("show 2");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myPanel.loadPanel(PANEL2);
            }
        });

        JPanel bot = new JPanel();
        bot.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        bot.add(b1);
        bot.add(b2);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bot, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

An it creates:

[image: View1]

[image: View2]